# Azure logic apps 'o365 connector' action 'send approval email' returning null for property 'useremailaddress'. Why?

Tags: azure, null, azure-logic-apps, email-address, office365connectors

Azure logic apps 'o365 connector' action 'send approval email' returning null for property 'useremailaddress'. Why?

The Azure logic apps documentation for the 'office 365 outlook connector' shows that the 'ApprovalEmailResponse' object returns 'SelectedOption' and 'UserEmailAddress'. I get the correct value back for 'SelectedOption' but 'UserEmailAddress' always returns 'null'.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#approvalemailresponse

How do I get the --> email address <-- of the user that selects 'Approve' or 'Reject' buttons in the email? If an email is forwarded to another person I would like to know who (email address) clicked approve or reject.

[image: Setup]

[image: RESPONSE REQUEST IN OUTLOOK]

[image: AFTER RESPONSE HAS BEEN RECORDED]

***This is what I get if I use the recommended settings mentioned in the replies below. For production we want to set "Use only HTML message" and "Show confirmation dialog" both set to "yes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... It looks like (in this particular action) the only way to get the email address of the person that clicks approve or reject is to not use HTML and to instead rely on using the action card, that is provided by the logic app action, in the email. With 'Hide HTML message' set to 'yes'. However... I was not able to find a way to render my custom card from the one provided in the email. As a workaround, I use markdown in the body of the action. Not great but looks the same as the HTML version I was going-for. If anyone can figure out how to edit/customize the card that is provided in the email by this specific logic app action. Please... let me and Microsoft (sarcasm) know.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from our end, we understood that the messages which are recorded as HTML messages aren't capturing all the responses. For this, Make sure you have the below parameters set `Hide HTML message` to 'yes'.

[image]

**RESPONSE REQUEST IN OUTLOOK**

[image]

**AFTER RESPONSE HAS BEEN RECORDED**

[image]

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Logic App outlook connector:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping but I still get 'null' back. I set it up exactly as you did. Here are the outputs results. I also have "use only HTML message" set to 'yes'. Any ideas??? "body": {
        "SelectedOption": "Approve",
        "UserEmailAddress": null,
        "UserTenantId": null,
        "UserId": null
    }

Comment: Could mimecast or permissions changes cause this? I swear it was working then just stopped :(

Comment: @WiredLessInTX try making use only HTML message to 'no'.

Comment: I should have mentioned this is for Logic Apps *Standard* single tenant. Can you try it that way please? Also, if I set 'use only HTML message' to 'no', I get 'Target URL not allowed' when I click 'Accept'.

Comment: @WiredLessInTX, yes even after doing in  Logic Apps Standard single tenant I could able to pull off and get the properties. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Did you use a shared mailbox or service account mailbox? I'm using a service account mailbox. Could that be the issue?

Comment: no. I'm using service account too. Would you mind adding screenshots of what are you receiving in your mail and logic app result?

Comment: I updated the question with screenshots using your same settings. If I use your recommended settings I get 'Target URL not allowed' when I click 'accept' or 'reject' buttons. For production we want to set "Use only HTML message" and "Show confirmation dialog" both set to "yes". Then we no-longer get the 'Target URL not allowed' error but we still don't get the 'UserEmailAddress'.